# AWS Elastic Beanstalk throws error cc1plus doesn't exist

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, requirements.txt

I'm currently deploying a fairly simple Django site to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but my most recent deployment failed with the following:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-activity.log
-------------------------------------
caused by: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): appdirs==1.4.3 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4==4.5.3 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
Collecting blessed==1.14.2 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading blessed-1.14.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (64kB)
Collecting boto==2.46.1 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading boto-2.46.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
Collecting cement==2.8.2 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading cement-2.8.2.tar.gz (165kB)
Collecting colorama==0.3.7 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 6))
  Downloading colorama-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Django==1.10.6 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 7))
Collecting django-ses==0.8.2 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 8))
  Downloading django-ses-0.8.2.tar.gz
Collecting docopt==0.6.2 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 9))
  Downloading docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz
Collecting future==0.16.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 10))
  Downloading future-0.16.0.tar.gz (824kB)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): html5lib==0.999 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 11))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): nameparser==0.4.0 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 12))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): packaging==16.8 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 13))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): PennSDK==1.5.3 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 14))
Collecting probableparsing==0.0.1 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 15))
  Downloading probableparsing-0.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting probablepeople==0.5.2 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 16))
  Downloading probablepeople-0.5.2.tar.gz (887kB)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyparsing==2.2.0 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 17))
Collecting python-crfsuite==0.9.1 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 18))
  Downloading python-crfsuite-0.9.1.tar.gz (400kB)
Collecting PyYAML==3.12 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 19))
  Downloading PyYAML-3.12.tar.gz (253kB)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests==2.4.3 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 20))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six==1.10.0 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 21))
Collecting tabulate==0.7.5 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 22))
  Downloading tabulate-0.7.5.tar.gz
Collecting termcolor==1.1.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 23))
  Downloading termcolor-1.1.0.tar.gz
Collecting wcwidth==0.1.7 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 24))
  Downloading wcwidth-0.1.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting websocket-client==0.40.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 25))
  Downloading websocket_client-0.40.0.tar.gz (196kB)
Collecting doublemetaphone (from probablepeople==0.5.2->-r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 16))
  Downloading DoubleMetaphone-0.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: wcwidth, blessed, boto, cement, colorama, django-ses, docopt, future, probableparsing, python-crfsuite, doublemetaphone, probablepeople, PyYAML, tabulate, termcolor, websocket-client
  Running setup.py install for cement
  Running setup.py install for django-ses
  Running setup.py install for docopt
  Running setup.py install for future
  Running setup.py install for python-crfsuite
    Complete output from command /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-snijpm6n/python-crfsuite/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-kgt8ascc-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/python/run/venv/include/site/python3.4/python-crfsuite:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pycrfsuite
    copying pycrfsuite/_dumpparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pycrfsuite
    copying pycrfsuite/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pycrfsuite
    copying pycrfsuite/_logparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pycrfsuite
    running build_ext
    building 'pycrfsuite._pycrfsuite' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/pycrfsuite
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/crfsuite
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/crfsuite/lib
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/crfsuite/lib/crf
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/crfsuite/lib/crf/src
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/crfsuite/swig
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/crfsuite/lib/cqdb
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/crfsuite/lib/cqdb/src
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/liblbfgs
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/liblbfgs/lib
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Icrfsuite/include/ -Icrfsuite/lib/cqdb/include -Iliblbfgs/include -Ipycrfsuite -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c pycrfsuite/_pycrfsuite.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/pycrfsuite/_pycrfsuite.o -std=c99
    gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Between this deployment and the last, it appears that installing one package, boto, installed a number of other dependencies that have ultimately prevented EB from being able to install all the packages from requirements.txt

This is my current requirements.txt:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
beautifulsoup4==4.5.3
blessed==1.14.2
boto==2.46.1
cement==2.8.2
colorama==0.3.7
Django==1.10.6
docopt==0.6.2
future==0.16.0
html5lib==0.999
nameparser==0.4.0
packaging==16.8
PennSDK==1.5.3
probableparsing==0.0.1
probablepeople==0.5.2
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-crfsuite==0.9.1
PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.4.3
six==1.10.0
tabulate==0.7.5
termcolor==1.1.0
wcwidth==0.1.7
websocket-client==0.40.0
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It looks like you need to have g++ installed first.

Comment: should I add g++ to requirements?

Comment: How are you setting up this machine?  Ultimately you've got a Python package (python-crfsuite) that isn't 100% pure Python and it needs a C++ compiler.  Elastic Beanstalk machines can have a [startup deployment hook](http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/29-aws-elasticbeanstalk-deployment-hooks) that would allow you to do something like `apt get install g++` (for Ubuntu based machines or `yum install gcc-c++` for CentOS based machines.